# Dataframe- minus minutes from timestamp column

Tags: scala, datetime, apache-spark, dataframe, jodatime

Environment: Spark 1.6 ; Scala

Simple question, but I did not get accurate answer. I have a dataframe  DF

```
id | cr_date
-----------------------
1| 2017-03-17 11:12:00
----------------------
2|2017-03-17 15:10:00
```

I need to minus 5 minutes from cr_date. I tried

`val DF2= DF.select ($"cr_Date".cast("timestamp").minusMinutes(5))` // Did not work

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
df.select(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("cr_dt")).minus(5 * 60), "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

There is no such `minusMinutes` method available in spark.
The above code should return expected results.

Comment: Thanks @undefined_variable, your code is working and that what I was looking for

Comment: @Jhon if you are satisfied with the answer you can accept it

Comment: similarly how can we add a timestamp to a dataframe?

Comment: There is plus method available... If you are talking about adding new column to dataframe use withColumn method

Comment: In spark 3 there is no `.minus` method. instead, you have to simply use the `-` operator.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone runs into the same issue, I found that using the above method maintains the year. For example I had a data frame with the timestamp "2015-01-01 00:00:00" when applying:

```
df.select(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("cr_dt")).minus(5 * 60), "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

I got the result "2015-12-31 23:55:00" however my expected result was "2014-12-31 23:55:00".
It seems that this is due to having "YYYY" as opposed to "yyyy". Making this change:

```
df.select(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("cr_dt")).minus(5 * 60), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

Gives the result I was looking for.

Comment: The pattern YYYY represents the year of the week of the date, for some reason.