# How can I convert a column of type date to a datetime, and add some minutes to it?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I can create a new column of type timestamp using `datetime.datetime()`:

`import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.types import *
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(datetime.date(2015,4,8),)], StructType([StructField("date", DateType(), True)]))
df = df.select(df.date, lit(datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 1)).alias('datetime'))
df.printSchema()
df.collect()`

which returns:

```
root
 |-- date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- datetime: timestamp (nullable = false)
Out[13]:
[Row(date=u'2015-04-08', datetime=datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 1))]
```

So far so good, I can synthesize a timestamp column. however what I actually want to do is convert the existing date value to a timestamp and add some arbitrary minutes to it. I've tried this:

```
import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.types import *
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(datetime.date(2015,4,8),)], StructType([StructField("date", DateType(), True)]))
df = df.select(df.date, lit(datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 1)).alias('datetime'))
df.printSchema()
df.collect()
```

but it fails with error:

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-4edbbc99537e> in <module>()
      2 from pyspark.sql.types import *
      3 df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(datetime.date(2015,4,8),)], StructType([StructField("date", DateType(), True)]))
----> 4 df = df.select(df.date, lit(datetime.datetime(year(df.date), 1, 1, 0, 1)).alias('datetime'))
      5 df.printSchema()
      6 df.collect()

TypeError: an integer is required
```

That's because `year()` returns a column, not an integer literal.

Anyone got any suggestions how I can achieve this? 
I'm using Spark v1.6.0 by the way and I don't have the option to use a later version.

Comment: Do you initially have a date as a string or date? See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039217/dataframe-minus-minutes-from-timestamp-column)

Comment: oops. yeah, it was a string, not a date. My bad. I've updated the question so that the date is explicitly created as a date. behaviour is the same though

Comment: @Psidom And your provided link solved the problem, thank you very very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can cast your date column to a timestamp column:

```
df = df.withColumn('date', df.date.cast('timestamp'))
```

You can add minutes to your timestamp by casting as long, and then back to timestamp after adding the minutes (in seconds - below example has an hour added):

```
df = df.withColumn('timeadded', (df.date.cast('long') + 3600).cast('timestamp'))
```

Comment: Thanks Bob. Nice solution, though I've gone with the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039217/dataframe-minus-minutes-from-timestamp-column linked to above by Psidom. Both work equally well tho, thank you.